# error CS0118: 'Invoice' is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, .net

```
namespace Vectigal.Invoice.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InvoicesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly InvoiceContext _context;

        public InvoicesController(InvoiceContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Invoices
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Invoice>>> GetInvoices()
        {
            return await _context.Invoices.ToListAsync();
        }
```

I get the error message when i try running this dotnet project.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When you ask a question like this, please indicate which line has the error (if double click the error, VS will jump to the offending line). That way, folks can quickly find the problem without having to compile your code in their heads.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Invoice` is a namespace (`Vectigal.Invoice`), not a type - exactly what the error says.

`IEnumerable<Invoice>` is malformed.  Did you declare something else called `Invoice` somewhere else?  If so, either change its name or change the name of the namespace so they don't collide.  Don't give two different things the same name.

You can always fully scope the name, alternatively, ie : `IEnumerable<SomeOtherNamespace.Invoice>`, but that gets a bit verbose.